# Dealing with unique constraints that should be replaced in django_rest_framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

tl;dr: How can I ignore (turn off) a unique constraint in django_rest_framework Create calls with a ListCreateAPIView, because I'm going to deal with it manually in the perform_create method?

Im using a third party library [django-push-notifications](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications).  It has a nice model for APNSDevice (apple push notification service device) that has a unique constraint on a registration_id field.

My problem is that sometimes I want to manually delete old values in the table that have the registration ID, so that I can insert a new value.  I'd like to use this serializer:

```
class APNSDeviceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = APNSDevice
        fields = ('name', 'active', 'device_id', 'registration_id')
```

along with this code for PUT

```
class MyAppleDevices(generics.ListCreateAPIView): 
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = APNSDeviceSerializer
    model = APNSDevice

    def get_queryset(self):
        return APNSDevice.objects.filter(user = self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print "Looking for old devices with registration id "+str(self.request.registration_id)
        oldDevices = APNSDevice.objects.filter(registration_id = self.request.registration_id)
        for oldDevice in oldDevices:
             oldDevice.delete()
        apnsDevice = serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

In other words, I'm trying to manually delete other entries that have the unique constraint in this particular PUT, so that I can insert the new one without violating the unique constraint. The problem is the validator runs before the perform_create method is called, and I can't figure out how to turn off the validator's unique constraint.  I tried adding this to the Serializer

```
    def get_validation_exclusions(self, instance = None):
        exclusions = super(APNSDeviceSerializer, self).get_validation_exclusions(instance)
        return exclusions + ['registration_id']
```

but it doesn't help so obviously I have no clue even though I've been pouring through the documentation and Stack Overflow posts.  Any help appreciated, thanks.  I suppose as a last resort I could remove the unique constraint from the model, but it is a valid constraint so I'd rather leave it in.

Answer (score -2):

I found this question because I had this exact problem with that exact library. You can get around it by subclassing the serializer and manually overriding the field definition:

```
class APNSDeviceSerializerWithNonUniqueRegistrationId(APNSDeviceSerializer):
    registration_id = serializers.CharField(min_length=64, max_length=64)

    class Meta(APNSDeviceSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ("name", "registration_id", "device_id", "active", "date_created")
```

Then, if you're using django-push-notifications, you'll also need to override the ViewSet that uses that serializer:

```
class APNSDeviceAuthorizedViewSetWithNonUniqueRegistrationId(AuthorizedMixin, APNSDeviceViewSet):
    """
    The out of the box viewset/serializer combo require the registration ID to be unique and won't
    allow setting a registration ID to a new user (which is useful if we have potentially more than
    one account on a device.)
    """
    serializer_class = APNSDeviceSerializerWithNonUniqueRegistrationId

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            try:
                existing_registration = APNSDevice.objects.get(
                    registration_id=serializer.validated_data['registration_id'])
                existing_registration.delete()
            except APNSDevice.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        return super(DeviceViewSetMixin, self).perform_create(serializer)
```